# Function gets called when the application is loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to check if the current date is before or after a date, for example if it's before it should show false, otherwise true.

The project is in Angular 8 and this is how it looks so far:

```
export class AppComponent {
    today = new Date();
    dateToCheck = new Date("2019-01-01");
    result = false;
    checkDate() {
        if(this.today < this.dateToCheck) {
           this.result = false;
        } else { this.result = true;
          }
    }  
}
```

this works fine if it is connected to a button in html and the button is clicked

```
<button (click)="checkDate()">check</button>
the result is: {{result}}
```

But is there a way to make it call itself when the page loads, without clicking that button?

Comment: There are probably a dozen ways to call a function in Angular or JavaScript on page load. Please be more specific.

Comment: Not exactly for this purpose was the function invented: "ngOnInit"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not call it in the constructor or `ngOnInit`:

> ngOnInit: A callback method that is invoked immediately after the default change detector has checked the directive's data-bound properties for the first time, and before any of the view or content children have been checked. It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    today = new Date();
    dateToCheck = new Date("2019-01-01");
    result = false;

    ngOnInit() {
       this.checkDate();
    }

    checkDate() {
        if(this.today < this.dateToCheck) {
           this.result = false;
        } else { 
           this.result = true;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: This answer caters to the OP's needs, but an explanation on why to call in the constructor/ngOnInit would be helpful.